# Facebook Share Android

Tags: android, facebook, fbsdksharedialog

I am trying to share something to Facebook. It was working fine previously. Suddenly it stopped working. 
Facebook dialog is not opening at all. 
Below is the code am using

```
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog((Activity) context);
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class))
{
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url))
                    .setQuote(text)
                    .build();

    LOGGER.info("showing Dialog");

    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
 }
```

Can anyone suggest what am doing wrong

Note: I have configured id given by facebook

Edit: When I checked the rootCause by Facebook CallbackManager, its showing 
      Error Cause: Invalid long: "null"
But am not sure what is going null

Answer (score 0):

After sometime it automatically started working.